# Strange issue with jar file

Tags: java, class, jar, zip, unzip

I have the following strange issue with jar file:

1. When using a jar file - everything is good.
2. Extracting the jar (using jar -xf) and archiving again - The application fails to run because of an incorrect package name.
3. I renamed the jar file to .zip - I saw that the name of the package is "pack1" instead of "Pack1".
   I noticed that when extracted the jar file using jar -xf, the directory of this package is incorrect.
4. Openning the jar file with decompiler (jd-gui) shows the correct name ("Pack1").

Can someone help me to understand this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using? If it is windows, does it handle long file names?

Comment: Compiled on SunOS. Extracted on Windows.

Comment: Which version of windows? It may not handle long file names reasonably.

Comment: windows 7. The file name is very short - 4 letters.

Comment: Windows 7 shouldn't have the problem I'm thinking of.